# Use complex type in stored procedure when inserting data to the database, using entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, database-first

I am using database first in an MVC application, and in certain situations I need to use stored procedures to map data from the database to complex types (and vise versa).

It was easy to setup the mapping to complex types, when **reading** data from database, but I can't seem to find out, how to map complex types to stored procedures when **writing** data to the database. It looks like it is only possible to use properties from the underlying entity itself, when choosing the mapping parameters.

I was wondering if it is even possible to use complex types when inserting, updating and deleting data using stored procedures.

Example:

```
--Database table--
ID int
StartDate varchar(8)

-- Complex type --
ID int
StartDate DateTime
```

I would like to create an instance of the complex type and insert its data into the database using a stored procedure. The conversion from DateTime -> string would be done in the stored procedure.

Is that possible?